# Slower CodeIgniter Loading Time: Base Classes

Tags: database, codeigniter, caching, routes

I'm creating a Database Driven Routes for my codeigniter application. The problem is that, if I have more than X dozens of rows in my tables, my application is running super slow ! The problem is that I'm not using or getting any informations from the routes tables that I create.

In fact, I'm using a routes files in the cache folder of my application.

So here is what I have without cache file and DB empty :

[image]

0.0071 / 0,0196 / 0.0268

Here is what I have with my 20.000 rows and my cache file : (20.000 lines for cache file)

[image]

0.2637 / 0,0114 / 0.2752

Here is what I have with empty DB and cache file : (20.000 lines for cache file)

[image]

0.0036 / 0.0142 / 0.0179

So, I don't know why I have so much difference between those three benchmarks !

Is there a way to cache de database or do something about it ?

If someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: How you added indexes on your mysql routes table? I'm not familiar with this "mysql routing" procedure but if your table is missing indexes, this might slow your application under heavy load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my first case I was using Hooks like this:

require_once APPPATH."config/database.php";

```
$hook['pre_system'] = array(
     'class'    => 'Router_Hook',
     'function' => 'get_routes',
     'filename' => 'Router_Hook.php',
     'filepath' => 'hooks',
     'params'   => array($db['default']['hostname'],$db['default']['username'],$db['default']['password'],$db['default']['database'],$db['default']['dbprefix'],)
                        );
```

In my router_hook files, I had :

```
function get_routes($params)
{
    global $DB_ROUTES;

    mysql_connect($params[0], $params[1], $params[2]);

    mysql_select_db($params[3]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$params[4]}routes";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $routes = array();
    while ($route = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $routes[$route['route']] = $route['controller'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
    mysql_close();
    $DB_ROUTES = $routes;
}
```

I had an include in my routes with the global variables in config/routes.php

Now I changed it for a cache version in the cache folder => cache/routes.php and I included it in my config/routes.php

So I don't need my hook anymore => Performance increase !

Comment: Either edit this to be a proper answer to your question and accept it, or delete the question. This answer isn't going to help anyone else who might stumble across your question in the future.